# perl how to change url in text file

Tags: perl, file, url, edit

how in the specified file  change the end of the url address ".pl" to ".en" and the penultimate ".com" to ".org"

for example:
http://www.addres.pl
change to:
http://www.addres.en

and if in addres exist like this
http://www.addres.com.pl
change to:
http://www.addres.org.en

and if its appear like this
http://www.addres.com.ru
then only change .com
http://www.addres.org.ru

example of text file input:

```
http://www.addres.org.en
http://www.addres.com.pl
http://www.addre.pl
http://www.addres.en
http://www.addres.ru
http://com ddd http://www.com.pl.com.pl.com.pl.com.pl
aaa http://www.addres.com.pl! bbb
ccc (http://www.addre.pl) ddd
```

example of console output:

```
http://www.addres.org.en
http://www.addres.org.en
http://www.addre.en
http://www.addres.en
http://www.addres.ru
http://com ddd http://www.com.pl.com.pl.com.pl.org.en
aaa http://www.addres.org.en! bbb
ccc (http://www.addre.en) ddd
```

for now i have this to check if input is a file

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use File::Find;

if (($#ARGV+1 != 1 )||(! -f $ARGV[0]))
{
  print "podaj plik\n";
  exit 1;
}

#!/usr/local/bin/perl
open (MYFILE, $ARGV[0]);
while (<MYFILE>) {
chomp;
my $url = $_;
for ($url) {
#s|(com)(.??)|org$2| and last;
s|com.pl|org.en| and last;
s|com[.]|org.| and last;
s|[.]pl|.en|; 
}
print "$url\n";
 }
close (MYFILE); 
exit 0;
```

how to make this

```
s|com[.]ru|org.ru| and last;
```

change all addres like this

```
s|com[.]??|org.??| and last;
```

where ?? can be for example ru, or en or all others then pl

Comment: this seems like a simple use of `s///` operators. Show what you've tried.

Comment: for now i have chek the input if its file only, im new in perl just starting

Comment: What does that have to do with the question? Show the code that opens and reads the file.

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty:

```
use strict;
while (<>) {
    s|com[.]pl\b|org.en| or
        s|[.]pl\b|.en|   or
        s|com[.]ru\b|org.ru|;
    print;
}
```

Pay attention to the regex order and call it from the command line: `perl script.pl in.txt`.

Then learn the proper three-argument way to [open](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html) files using lexical variables for filehandles (to prevent global file handles with names as common as MYFILE to clobber one another + get file to close when the lexical variable goes out of scope).

**Added:**

Looking at your new sample lines, I think you probably need something more like this (I included the regex you asked for at the end of your last edit):

```
while (<>) {
    s|com[.]pl([\s!)])|org.en\1| 
      or s|[.]pl([\s!)])|.en\1| 
      or s|com[.]([!pl])([\s!)])|org.\1\2| ;
    print;
}
```

For further advice, read my comments below.

Comment: but it doesnt for for that urls:
`aaa http://www.addres.org.en! bbb
ccc (http://www.addre.en) ddd`

Comment: sorry i pasted output
for this it doesnt work `aaa http://www.addres.com.pl! bbb
ccc (http://www.addre.pl) ddd`

Comment: I did not see the sample input file. I thought the file had but URLs. I modified the code. You should read [prelretut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html): regex aren't that scary.

Comment: I added word boundaries to handle the cases you provided in a second or third stage. You may consider to use [`URI::Find`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/URI-Find/lib/URI/Find.pm) if your text file is really tricky. And [`URI::Split`](http://search.cpan.org/~gaas/URI-1.60/URI/Split.pm) if you plan to reconstruct complex URLs.